# How to use a while loop before assigning the outcomes to a vector in R?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

My simulated experiment is as follows:

1. Roll a fair die to get a number X between 1 to 6.
2. Flip a fair coin X number of times (i.e. the number from the die roll) and record the number of heads.

This is the code (within a loop) for my experiment:

```
Youtcomes <- rep(0, 100)
for (i in 1:100) {
    X <- sample(1:6, 1, replace=TRUE, rep(1,6)/6)
    Y <- sample(c("H", "T"), X, replace=TRUE, rep(1,2)/2)
    # assign output inside the loop with [i] indexing
    Youtcomes[i] <- sum(Y == "T")
}
```

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient loop but unfortunately, I have been instructed to do it this way.

I then need to create a random variable N that is defined as the number of runs of the experiment until an outcome `Y>=5` occurs for the first time.

How would I go about designing a loop to simulate this value?

Comment: Can you add some more information? How is your loop working? Is it building something? What is the desired output?

Comment: I've edited it, hopefully that's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop as follows:

```
one.simulation <- function() {
    N <- 0
    Y <- 0
    while (Y < 5) {
        X <- sample(6, 1)
        Y <- sum(sample(c(Heads = 1, Tails = 0), X, replace=TRUE))
        N <- N+1
    }
    N
}

set.seed(1234)
one.simulation()
# [1] 50

replicate(100, one.simulation())
#   [1]  20   9  11  57  35  35  14 106  11  14   6 113   8  28 125  29   4  12   3
#  [20]  19  39   4  13  32  23  96  19  20  47  68  96  65  18  71  39  51   6  22
#  [39] 111   3 109   9  22  18  99   1 151  85   3   2 102  46  18  31  41  21  14
#  [58]  75  10  56   3  63  79  12  59  68  31  47  35  15  14  38  11  36  26  24
#  [77]  24  45  43  15  81   1  16  57  29   6  64  11  15  47 107 116   8  62 146
#  [96] 217  78  28   9 141
```

Comment: What does the set.seed do?

Comment: It sets the random generator in a specific state, so that when you or me use it here, we both get the same result (`50`). It's still random, but reproducible.

Comment: I see. But the thing is, I'm not supposed to be generating a random number, but rather simulating the experiment?

Comment: But the sampling to generate `X` and `Y` uses it

Comment: I don't understand? I'm sure what it's supposed to do is go through the 'experiment' and create a random variable from that.

Comment: When you run this thing over and over, don't include `set.seed`, that's all.

Comment: Ignore what I said, I understand what it's doing now.

Comment: @flodel - edited to show your `while` loop in context of the `for`

Comment: Would it be alright to omit the set.seed if I'm only running it once? I still don't think I understand its purpose in this case...

Comment: Why do N and Y have to be defined as 0 to start with?

Comment: `N` starts at `0` because you have not rolled any dice yet. `Y` can start at any value less than `5` so that the code enters the `while` loop.

Comment: Also, why has the coding of the experiment been changed? For example, why is         X <- sample(1:6, 1, replace=TRUE, rep(1,6)/6) now      X <- sample(6, 1)

Comment: If you read the doc (`?sample`), you will realize they do the same thing.

Comment: But they don't for when I use my original code, I get an error message saying: " In while (Y < 5) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: @flodel has given it to you on a platter - the code is changed because it is more concise. Don't worry about `set.seed`, it has been included so that if you run the code you will get the same output. When you use the function in the answer, you can see you get as many values as you want.

Comment: @flodel has been very helpful, I just want to make sure I fully understand the code.

Comment: If I wanted to run this while loop 10000 times and store the observed values in another vector, how would I do that?

Comment: Like this: `results <- replicate(10000, one.simulation())`

Comment: Is one.simlation now a function?